# Jquery UI resizable handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using jQuery UI resizable and I want to have a title for each handler.

Like if I an hovering on 'east -handler' then a tooltip should appear saying 'that move to the right'. I was trying to do with jQuery `attr()` but not able to do so. Any help is appreciated. And one more thing I am having more than one element on which I am applying resizable method so all should get the same "title".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-e').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', 'hello');
  });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Resizable functionality</title>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <style>
    #resizable {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      padding: 0.5em;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>

  <!-- Javascript -->
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#resizable").resizable();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- HTML -->
  <div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Pull my edges to resize me!!</h3>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Questions in Stackoverflow should contains your code effort otherwise it consider as off-topic. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Good luck!

Comment: I am using this but not working

Comment: Can you make your snippet working? I mean that we actually see it in action.. Please, use [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: I just want to give a title to a div. How to do this? and this div is the corner handle of resizable Jquery library

Comment: Your code does adding `title` to the `div` but my guess is that you need this attribute for the plugin so it's not enough. I understand that you are using resizable plugin but to help you we probably want to see it in action so a working snippet will help. So help we to help you. Make sense, right?

Comment: <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div> these divs are automatically created and now the control is on 'South-east' and I want a title when i hover the last div

Comment: Sorry but without a **working** snippet I couldn't help you. I hope you understand. It's not that hard to create snippet..

Comment: I have added  snippet. Will you please tell me the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your code **after** you initialise the plugin. Like this:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Resizable functionality</title>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <style>
    #resizable {
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      padding: 0.5em;
      text-align: center;
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>

  <!-- Javascript -->
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#resizable").
        resizable().
        find('.ui-resizable-se').attr('title', 'hello');
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- HTML -->
  <div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Pull my edges to resize me!!</h3>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]